# Getting string from CharField

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I've been looking online but to no avail. I'm trying to get a url string from a CharField in Django.

```
class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ['url']

def get_url(self):
    temp = self.fields['url']
    string = temp.to_python(temp)
    return string
```

This returns a unicode object, but it doesn't print properly as we see in the terminal output:

```
url is: 
<django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x10781b410>
```

The model is here:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    article_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="generic title")

    def __unicode__(self):
        val = str(self.url) + ", " + str(self.article_title)
        return val
```

Using Python 2.7.
Can anyone help with this?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you add your model please?which python version do you use?

Comment: @LouisBarranqueiro Added the model there, and it's Python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should in your views.py:

```
form = EntryForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
if form.is_valid():
    url = form.cleaned_data['url']
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that makes sense!

Comment: Made this the answer because of the clarification that is_valid() will call clean() behind the scenes, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Form.clean()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.clean) function to get form data.

```
def get_url(self):
    cleaned_data = self.clean()
    return cleaned_data.get('url')
```

Why not use `is_valid()`?

> `is_valid()` calls `clean()` on the form automatically. You use
>   `is_valid()` in your views, and `clean()` in your form classes.

This function is `Form` function, not `View` function.

Comment: You shouldn't call `clean()` manually, `is_valid()` will call `clean()` behind the scene.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this makes sense now. I wasn't aware of the .clean() function, thanks for the link to the doc too.